# How can I keep the discord bot active without pycharm?

Tags: python

when you make a discord bot with javascript

```
"echo off" 
color 0f
cls
:a
node bot.js
goto a"
```

When I put this command in the folder and run it as .bat, it could run without the need for a client. Do you know how I can do this with python?

Answer (score 2):

To run a Python Code you need to host it on a 24/7 client or server. You can use your own server like on AWS or Azure, and actually then what you do is keep it 24/7 running to keep your bot. Or you can use a hosting platform like DigitalOcean or Autocode.

Comment: Also, if you mean when your device is running, you can just like open a terminal and `py discordbot.py` for example which runs to bot and keep it running in the background while you are browsing the web for example.!

Comment: Yes @Omar The Dev, I'm pretty sure the OP wasn't asking for an host server, but this is a solution that should be know by them. +1

Answer (score 1):

```
"echo off" 
color 0f
cls
:a
python bot.py
goto a"
```

Do you mean something like this?

Notice that the command `python` doesn't work for all the operative systems, you may need to use some aliases like `py`, and in case you have more than one version installed you may need to specify `py -3`.

---

Anyway you can "keep the discord bot active" running it from the IDLE Shell or from the command prompt of your operative system.

Comment: Or you can try `py` or `py -3` if `python` does not work on windows.

Comment: You are right, it depends on your os. I'm going to edit the answer, thank you @skywalker